Let $C_s=\{z:|z|>s\}$ and suppose $f:C_s\to C_s$ is analytic. Define $g(z)=1/f(1/z)$, where $0<|z|<1/s$. How do you extend function g to $0$?
Let $C_s=\{z:|z|>s\}$ and suppose $f:C_s\to C_s$ is analytic. Define $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$, where
$0<|z|<\frac{1}{s}$. How do you extend the function $g$ to $0$?
I know $g'(z)=-\frac{1}{f(1/z)^2}\cdot f'(1/z)(-\frac{1}{z^2})$. I am guessing as $z\rightarrow 0$, we have $f(1/z)\to f(\infty)$ so $g(z)=1/f(\infty)$ but I don't know if $f(\infty)$ is defined or not. However, $f$ is analytic on $C_s$. How do you extend function $g$ to $0$? Please help.

note that $g$ is bounded (since $f$ is inferior bounded) and apply the Riemann extension theorem

Can you elaborate on that?

$g$ maps $0<|z|<\frac{1}{s}$ to itself which means that it is bounded and holomorphic; the Riemann extension theorem says that such a map extends analytically to zero (proof: $zg$ is continuous at $0$ when extended by $0$ there; hence $z^2g$ is differentiable there so is analytic on the disc $|z|<\frac{1}{s}$; but looking at its power series we have $z^2g(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ and the boundness of $g$ forces $a_0=a_1=0$ so dividing by $z^2$ we have that $g(z)=\sum a_{n+2}z^n$ is analytic on that disc too)

Thanks Conrad. Please check my proof below if it is correct: For $0<|w|<1/s,1/w\in \C_s$, so we may define
$$g(w)=\frac 1{f(\frac 1w)}.$$ Given $f$ is analytic on $C_s$, $f$ is analytic at $1/w$ which implies $g$ is analytic at $w$. Thus derivative $g'$ is bounded in the neighborhood of $w=0$.\newline
Thus $$|g'(w)|=\frac{|f'(1/w)|}{|w^2f(1/w)^2|}\le M \text{ for some }M\ge 0.$$ Hence $|f'(1/w)|\le M|w^2|\cdot |f(1/w)|^2$ which implies $|f'(1/w)|\to 0$ as $w\to 0.$ Thus $f(1/w)$ is a constant at $w=0$. If we define $\lim\limits_{w\to 0}|f(1/w)|=s$ then $|g(0)|=1/s.$

I have to define $g$ at $0$ which I did above. Is that correct?

Anyone know what $g(0)$ is?  Can it be arbitrarily set as above to $|g(0)|=1/s$ or as Conrad gave $g(z)=\sum a_{n+2}z^n$ which forces it to $g(0)=0$?

Conrad's give $g(0) =a_2$.
